# Finding the particular solution using method of undetermined coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me to solve the second order differential equation, I'm stuck at finding the particular solution by using undetermined coefficient.
$$y''+y'+y=\sin^2 x$$
Is it the particular solution have the form such that $Y(x)=A\sin^2 x + B\cos^2 x$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider
$$\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x=1-\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}$$

I'll put down the solution in a while if you update your further attempt.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no particular solution of the form $A\sin^2 (x) + B\cos^2 (x)$ (see the P.S. below).

Note that $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$. Moreover, $0$  and $2i$, complex numbers associated to the functions $1$ and $\cos(2x)$) are not roots of the characteristic polynomial $z^2+z+1$, then a particular solution should have the form (see [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)):
$$A\cdot 1+B\cdot \sin(2x)+C\cdot \cos(2x)$$
where $A,B,C$ are constants to be found. Can you take it from here?

P.S. Note that the dimension of $\text{span}\left(\{1,\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\}\right)$ is $3$, whereas the dimension of $\text{span}\left(\{\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)\}\right)=\text{span}\left(\{1,\cos(2x)\}\right)$ is $2$. So why is there no particular solution of the form $A\sin^2 (x) + B\cos^2 (x)$?